# USB HD shows in 'Device Manager' but not 'Disk Management'

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

After various software and hardware (driver) issues on my laptop, I decided to back-up and then format, reinstalling Windows 7.

While reaching for the portable drive, I dropped it, less than a foot. It really wasn't much of a fall, so that could be coincidence.

Now, when I plug it into the laptop, I hear the disk spinning (it sounds normal), and **it does "pop up"** in `Device Manager` and `Devices and Printers` like normal, but *not* in windows explorer or `Disk Management`, and the drive isn't detected by 2 free recovery apps I've tried.

<sub><sub>. . . **Click images to enlarge.**</sub></sub>
[image: img1] 
[image: img2]

The **Troubleshooter** found nothing wrong, and **"Eject"** take a few minutes before it says it can't locate the device "so be sure to close all files before unplugging it".

[image: img3]

The last thing that I tried was **uninstalling the drivers** for the 'USB Mass Storage Device' and the 'Seagate Portable USB Device'.

When I rebooted the drivers re-installed, and then I got:

[image: img4]

It sounds promising but the drive still doesn't show in Explorer or Disk Management.

---

## <sub>**Any suggestions, please?**   (either physically, or in Windows 7 or **Ubuntu**?)</sub>

<sub>This drive is where I **backup** anything important, and this happened during the moment between *backup→format→restore*, so **I've lost *everything**** . . . Most valuable: 1000s of irreplaceable family photos</sub>

Comment: I don't see a screenshot of disk management.  The last screenshot indicates the drive requires a file system and a drive letter.  Hopefully, you have a backup, because it does not appear the drive currently has a drive system.  What exactly is your question, edit your question, to include what you are trying to achieve (hard to tell if you are asking for help with data recovery or something else).

Comment: If the drive does not show up in Disk Manager either, then the drive is most likely damaged beyond simple repair. It is likely then, that the controller suffered from the impact and needs to be replaced. If the harddisk does not have data that you really need to get back at all costs, it will be cheaper to replace the drive.

Comment: @ashleedawg I am sorry this happened. =/ Not to sound alarmist, but if you can ever manage to get access to this drive, I would back up the contents *immediately*. I had a similar issue with a Seagate and was able to get it running a handful of times simply by adding and removing it from the system. But I didn't realize I needed to retrieve my data when it was working, so it ended badly. It may not be worth much now, but as a note, hard drives are the single-most common pieces of computer hardware to fail in my experience. For the future, two backups are always better than one.

Comment: Drive is damaged from the drop. I would not trust it even if you can get it back online.

Comment: The USB controller (an interface card in the case) is different from the HDD itself. You have only proven that the USB interface is OK.